# Rename all empty folders with `$ empty`

Tags: command-line, mv

I have many folders that I have ended up with too many `empties` in the folder names and I need to remove all the `empty` and leave the folders with `$1.empty`

Of course my logic is flawed here as I am not sure how to get the `new` file name. I can only get what is matching from regex.

```
#!/bin/sh

for I in `cat filelist`;
do
     # for renaming, use mv
    NEWNAME = `$I.empty`
    echo $NEWNAME 
done
```

The goal is to replace folders that have `$ empty.empty` then be `$.empty`. The folders that do not contain `empty.empty` should be left alone.

[image]

Comment: is it always `empty.empty` or can it be `empty.empty.empty` or more ?

Comment: just ` empty.empty` :)

Comment: You should read [How can I read a file (data stream, variable) line-by-line (and/or field-by-field)?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `rename`:

```
rename 's/ empty\.empty$/.empty/' *empty.empty
```

You might need to install `rename`:

```
sudo apt install rename
```

---

Alternative with [pure `bash`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html):

```
for d in *empty; do
    mv -i "$d" "${d% empty*}.empty"
done
```

Comment: bring back your other suggestions please :) Not everyone wants to install `rename` :)

Comment: `rename` is installed by default in ubuntu. Also, the other options did not care about OPs wish that the final name should be `$.empty`. They made it be `$ empty`.

Comment: Ye, now I have a few folders named `$ empty` and a few named `$.empty` lol opps

Comment: Sorry for that, you may use `rename 's/ empty$/.empty/' *' empty'` to fix that.

Comment: Christ that is a quick command

Comment: `rename` is not default on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS :) but if the others did not work then I agree.

Comment: You're right. `rename` is not default anymore ... such a beautiful command!

Comment: @Smurfz87 Now I have a good working solution without `rename`.